# PHP get file with input text

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a php page:

```
<?php


$stats = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test/stats/$name.txt');
$name = $_POST['stat'];
echo "$stats";
echo "$name";

?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="stat" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I want to get a custom file from the text form, by just inputting the name of the file, but my code is not working. thanks!

Comment: Think it might have anything to do with how `$name` is given a value AFTER it is used in `$stats`?

Comment: `$stats` and `$name` are interchanged. First `$name = $_POST['stat'];` then `$stats = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/stats/$name.txt");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this code will be not working. Try below code :

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['stat'];

    $stats = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/stats/$name.txt");
```

?>

You are making two mistakes.

First you are taking the name of the file after the code where you need the file name.

Second:  php when you place a php variable name in single quotes " '' " like in your case, it is rendered as it is, and its value is not rendered. But if you place the php variable in double quotes, its value is rendered / displayed .

Try this now, and if you still have any question, let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stat'])) {
  $name = $_POST['stat'];
  // note the double quote here
  $stats = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/stats/$name.txt");
  echo "$stats";
  echo "$name";
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="stat" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Dont forget to protect yours files (excluding "../" )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// switch the order around
$name = $_POST['stat'];
// and remove the variable from a single quoted string.
$stats = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test/stats/'.$name.txt);
echo "$stats";
echo "$name";

?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="stat" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```